# Android Room giving error "Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema" but exported schema is correct

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, data-persistence

I am migrating from SQlite to room in my existing application. Therefore I created migration strategy to create new temporary tables, copy existing data into temporary tables and delete old tables and rename new tables.

After migrating, I checked my exported schema and it is exactly the same as expected schema but  I still get the error of my old schema is found and receiving error below. Main differences on the schema errors are "type" and #notNull" but I already corrected them during the migration

> Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema:
> User(com.afl.waterReminderDrinkAlarmMonitor.model.User)

My User Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "User" )
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int = 0,
    var age: Int = 0,
    var weight: Int = 0,
    var gender: String = "",
    var metric: String = "",
    var water: Int = 0
)
```

AppDatabase

```
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dao(): Dao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    val migration_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

            //COPY USER TABLE
            // Create new  table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTmp ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, $COL_WEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL, $COL_GENDER  TEXT NOT NULL,$COL_METRIC TEXT NOT NULL, $COL_AGE INTEGER NOT NULL, $COL_WATER INTEGER NOT NULL)")
            // Copy the data
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO UserTmp ($COL_ID, $COL_WEIGHT, $COL_GENDER, $COL_METRIC,$COL_AGE, $COL_WATER) SELECT $COL_ID, $COL_WEIGHT, $COL_GENDER, $COL_METRIC,$COL_AGE, $COL_WATER FROM $TABLE_NAME ")
            // Remove the old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE $TABLE_NAME")
            // Change the table name to the correct one
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserTmp RENAME TO $TABLE_NAME")

            //COPY DRUNK TABLE
            // Create new table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DrunkTmp ($COL_ID_DRUNK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, $COL_DATE_DRUNK TEXT NOT NULL, $COL_TIME_DRUNK TEXT NOT NULL,$COL_DRINK_DRUNK TEXT NOT NULL, $COL_AMOUNT_DRUNK INTEGER NOT NULL ,$COL_METRIC_DRUNK TEXT NOT NULL)")
            // Copy the data
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO DrunkTmp ($COL_ID_DRUNK, $COL_DATE_DRUNK, $COL_TIME_DRUNK, $COL_DRINK_DRUNK, $COL_AMOUNT_DRUNK, $COL_METRIC_DRUNK) SELECT $COL_ID_DRUNK, $COL_DATE_DRUNK, $COL_TIME_DRUNK, $COL_DRINK_DRUNK, $COL_AMOUNT_DRUNK, $COL_METRIC_DRUNK FROM $TABLE_NAME_DRUNK")
            // Remove the old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE $TABLE_NAME_DRUNK")
            // Change the table name to the correct one
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DrunkTmp RENAME TO $TABLE_NAME_DRUNK")

            //COPY NOT TABLE
            // Create new table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NotificationTmp ($COL_ID_NOT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, $COL_PREF_NOT INTEGER NOT NULL, $COL_START_NOT INTEGER NOT NULL, $COL_FINISH_NOT INTEGER NOT NULL,$COL_INTERVAL_NOT INTEGER NOT NULL)")
            // Copy the data
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO NotificationTmp ($COL_ID_NOT, $COL_PREF_NOT, $COL_START_NOT, $COL_FINISH_NOT, $COL_INTERVAL_NOT) SELECT $COL_ID_NOT, $COL_PREF_NOT, $COL_START_NOT, $COL_FINISH_NOT, $COL_INTERVAL_NOT FROM $TABLE_NAME_NOT ")
            // Remove the old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE $TABLE_NAME_NOT")
            // Change the table name to the correct one
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE NotificationTmp RENAME TO $TABLE_NAME_NOT")
        }

    }

        fun getDatabase(context: Context?): AppDatabase {

            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context?.applicationContext!!,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
                )
                    .addMigrations(migration_1_2)
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Exported Schema for User

```
  {
    "tableName": "User",
    "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `age` INTEGER NOT NULL, `weight` INTEGER NOT NULL, `gender` TEXT NOT NULL, `metric` TEXT NOT NULL, `water` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))",
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldPath": "id",
        "columnName": "id",
        "affinity": "INTEGER",
        "notNull": true
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "age",
        "columnName": "age",
        "affinity": "INTEGER",
        "notNull": true
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "weight",
        "columnName": "weight",
        "affinity": "INTEGER",
        "notNull": true
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "gender",
        "columnName": "gender",
        "affinity": "TEXT",
        "notNull": true
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "metric",
        "columnName": "metric",
        "affinity": "TEXT",
        "notNull": true
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "water",
        "columnName": "water",
        "affinity": "INTEGER",
        "notNull": true
      }
    ],
    "primaryKey": {
      "columnNames": [
        "id"
      ],
      "autoGenerate": false
    },
    "indices": [],
    "foreignKeys": []
  }
```

and finally the error I receive it

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: User(com.afl.waterReminderDrinkAlarmMonitor.model.User).
>
> Expected: TableInfo{name='User', columns={weight=Column{name='weight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, gender=Column{name='gender', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, metric=Column{name='metric', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, water=Column{name='water', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>
> Found: TableInfo{name='User', columns={gender=Column{name='gender', type='VARCHAR(256)', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, metric=Column{name='metric', type='VARCHAR(256)', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, weight=Column{name='weight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, water=Column{name='water', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question misses the pre-populated database, which either resides in `assets` or elsewhere; as the mismatch is actually in that file and a migration would need to load it and then change the column. As one can see, table `User` has the wrong data-type for columns `gender` and `metric`:

```
Expected: TableInfo{name='User', columns={
       id=Column{name='id',         type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
       age=Column{name='age',       type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null',
       weight=Column{name='weight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       gender=Column{name='gender',    type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       metric=Column{name='metric',    type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       water=Column{name='water',   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found:   TableInfo{name='User', columns={
       id=Column{name='id',              type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
       age=Column{name='age',            type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue ='null',
       weight=Column{name='weight',      type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       gender=Column{name='gender', type='VARCHAR(256)', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       metric=Column{name='metric', type='VARCHAR(256)', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
       water=Column{name='water',        type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Editing the packaged database on a computer might be the least effort.

Comment: Ahh thanks to your answer. I realized that I was keeping old SQLite Database Helper class which creates the database first with different version numbers and then my migration object couldnt handle the migration because version numbers wasnt matching